# ASP.Net Session values not being kept

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

Hi I am working with an ASP.Net website and I am looking to pass session values from one sub to another in vb.net.

When I built this and was testing it worked fine and the values were being stored, however, now when I try and pass a new method / sub the session values it no longer has them and throws the error

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

For instance I am setting a session value like this

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
For Each status As ListItem In Me.statuscblist.Items
    If status.Selected = True Then
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0},", status.Value))
    End If
Next
Session("selectedStatus") = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(",")
```

This then gets passed to another method as part of the same button click event.

But when I want to use the same session variable like this in a new button click event its not finding the session value.

```
Dim reportStatus As String = Session("selectedStatus").ToString()
```

I would be extremely grateful if anyone can help me solve this issue.

Comment: Can it be that the other event handler is called before the one where you assign the session variable?

Comment: no, as the button click where I am seeing the issue is not enable until a search is completed

Comment: Could it be that the session state is disabled either for the application (in web.config) or for the page (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306996)?

Comment: no, i have looked at this too and the session is still getting stripped away

Comment: Any call to Session.Clear() in the application?

Comment: no, no call to session.clear()

Comment: Do this test: try retrieving the value from the session immediately after it is added. This will tell you if the session is ignoring the value when it is added or if the value is lost afterwards.

Comment: @HashPsi i am defiantly getting the values because from one button click event they are working, but on the next button click event they are gone.

Comment: Check the SessionId property when you put the value in and when you read it. Is it the same?